# Set WPF DataGridRow Background Color Based on a Color property of a concrete object

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've seen this question asked several times, and it seems like in every case the color is being set in the xaml. I already have the colors mapped the way I want in my object. Please see code:

```
public class Alert
{
     public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
     public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
     public string Event { get; set; }
     public string AreaDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a list of Alerts bound to the datagrid.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        this.Alerts.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Header = "Expires",
            Binding = new Binding("Expires")
        });

        this.Alerts.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Header = "Event",
            Binding = new Binding("Event")
        });

        this.Alerts.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
        {
            Header = "Area Description",
            Binding = new Binding("AreaDescription")
        });

        this.Alerts.ItemsSource = new FeatureCollection().GetFeatures().GetAlerts();
    }
}
```

My xaml:

```
    <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="Alerts" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The rowstyle setter above didn't work. I also tried using data triggers to no avail.

What should happen is the row should get its color from the BackgroundColor property inside the Alert class. The background color is set within those chained methods on this line "new FeatureCollection().GetFeatures().GetAlerts();" That code is not listed here, just know the color is already set, like BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;

Any help would be appreciated. I know this has sort of been asked before, but those answers did not work for me. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from the fact that `BackGroundcolor` is not a `Color` but a brush.
So this would work:

```
public class Alert
{
    public SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string AreaDescription { get; set; }
}
```

and maybe something like this:

```
alerts.Add(new Alert() { BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua)});
alerts.Add(new Alert() { BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) });
alerts.Add(new Alert() { BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) });
alerts.Add(new Alert() { BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow) });
```

If you want something even more fancy you could use the `Brush` type:

```
public Brush BackgroundColor { get; set; }
```

and

```
alerts.Add(new Alert() { BackgroundColor = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Black, Colors.Red, 30) });
alerts.Add(new Alert() { BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) });
```

Comment: Thank you @Bob. I will check this out when I get home and let you know how it works!

Comment: I changed the property but now I need the correct syntax for the xaml. So far the background color doesn't do anything in my datagrid.

Comment: Actually I copied/pasted your XAML code, and it works for me. The problem would be rather into the binding logic. If you add the `Alert` object during runtime without calling `GetFeatures().GetAlerts()` again, nothing will happen.